# Parent to child view event binding relationships

Tags: javascript, events, model-view-controller, event-handling, dom-events

I'm wondering about where events should be set in a parent-child relationship. It's not a specific problem, just a best practices I guess. My specific case:

I have a `Dropdown` which contains of a `Button` and a `List`. Describing the action, you press the button and the list appears. You click an item in the list, and that item is selected and the list disappears.

So the first thing is that since the view is initialized as a `Dropdown`, the person making it shouldn't need to reach in and deal with the `Button` or `List` view. All methods should be called on the parent view, and events might need to be bubbled up from the child.

So for example, instead of doing: `this.dropdown.button.press();`, `Dropdown` provides its own `press` method which just calls `Button`'s press method.

When the user presses the button, `Button` fires a `press` event that `Dropdown` is listening to.

```
onButtonPress : function () {

    if (!this.isExpanded()) {
        this.expand();
    }

    this.trigger('press');
},
```

And `Dropdown` triggers press on itself, so that developer can get the press event without reaching in to `dropdown.button`.

Here's where the first question comes. Should `Dropdown` expand itself in `onButtonPress` or should `onButtonPress` just trigger a press, and then have the expansion listening on `Dropdown`'s own `press` event:

```
onButtonPress : function () {

    this.trigger('press');
},

onPress : function () {

    if (!this.isExpanded()) {
        this.expand();
    }
},
```

And then it gets more complicated, should `Dropdown`'s `expand` method just trigger `expand` on itself:

```
expand : function () {

    if (this.isEnabled()) {

        this.setState('expanded', true);

        this.trigger('expand');
    }

    return this;
},

onExpand : function () {

    this.list.show();
},
```

or should it be the one that `show`s the `List`:

```
expand : function () {

    if (this.isEnabled()) {

        this.setState('expanded', true);

        this.list.show();

        this.trigger('expand');
    }

    return this;
},
```

I guess I'm just wondering about best practices for deciding where to bind events in a parent/child relationship. How to avoid confusing situations and possibly circular event calling.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: To determine "best" you first need to define your criteria for measurement.

Comment: Probably: most performant and easy to read/keep in mind while working with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the DOM for this instead of triggering an event manually. If you want to have an event hit the parent first, then set the capture to true, or false if you want the event to bubble.

this allows an event handler to be called during the capture phase, so parent DOM elements get event first:

```
el.bind('someevent', somefunction, true);
```

this bubbles, hence children receive event first, and handler is called when children receive event.

```
el.bind('someevent', somefunction, false);
```

In general keep it simple. You can also use the delegation programming pattern where the parent will get the events for itself and the children, so you can avoid confusion and potentially can save memory with larger applications.